# Flattening column data with split then merging df with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, split, concatenation

Using `names = df['Name and Location'].str.split(',', expand=True)`
I am able to split this dense data at delimiters like colons.

I'm stuck on how to recombine the data into a flatter record. I've tried:

```
pd.concat([df, names])
```

Records end at "complaint #", and begin at **date:** which is in another column.

```
**Last_Name , First_Name**
City: City_Name
County: OUT_OF_STATE
Zip Code: 00000
License #: AA0000000
Complaint # AA00000000000

**Company:** Company_Name,_INC
City: City_Name
County: County_Name
Zip Code: 00000
Company: Company_Name LIC AA0000
City: City_Name
County: County_Name
Zip Code: 00000
License: string_or_int
Complaint # AA00000000000

**Last_Name**, First_Name
Company: Company_Name
City: City_Name
County: County_Name
Zip Code: 00000
License #: AA00000000000
Complaint # AA00000000000
```

Ideally, each "record" would be flat, like:

```
First Name Last Name Company City County Zip Code License Complaint Date The String Why the String 

Last_name_1 First_name_1 Company_Name_1 City_1 County_1 00001 AA000000 string_1 why_string_1
```

Comment: Are you able to provide a sample of the data?

Comment: Do you mind if the specifics are redacted? I can include "city:" but not city name, etc.

Comment: @Megan the actually data doesn't matter at all - it just needs to be structurally similar to your real data so that the code we provide based on your dummy data will work with your real data.

Comment: @richardec gotcha. I added some redacted dummy data. Thanks!

Comment: `city` comes up twice in the same 'row'.  is this correct, because the dataframe would not like this...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @D.L Glad you asked, as I was worrying about clarity there. If you mean City : City Name, then imagine City Name being "Austin" etc. I should have been more clear and will edit.
If you mean that the data is ugly and needs to be parsed and flattened, then yes, I agree. That's the goal.

Comment: @MeganPerry,  i have prepared  a large part of the code,  but because it is not complete i would be downvoted for posting an answer.  i should you how to [1] read the file, [2] split the data, [3] parse the data into a dataframe.  (the data might need two dataframes if the datasets (companies and individuals) are sufficiently different.  maybe check and repost that same data.

Comment: @D.L I very much appreciate your time. I am not sure that I understand your comment, but will gladly repost whatever is helpful. Could you clarify? Thank you again.

Comment: okay. @MeganPerry:  i suggest you break the question into 3 smaller questions and post those.  it will be easier for the community to answer and more helpful to you. Each of those steps is easy and your 3 smaller questions will be much clearer to both yourself and others.

Comment: here is a guide:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @D.L Will do, after working through the example page you posted. I am grateful for the mentorship on proper posts here.

Comment: @MeganPerry.  everyone starts from the begining. You are welcome.

Comment: @D.L Hope that this one is clearer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71591796/flattening-data-using-split-around-delimiters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To split at a delimiter, and create and combine a new column with the existing df, use:

```
df = pd.concat((df, df['Column_to_Split'].str.split('String_to_Go:', expand=True)), axis=1, ignore_index=True)
```

Any delimiter can be used, including an empty string. The key here is `expand = True` as it creates a new column, which was the goal.